# Only one searchpane showing up in DataTables table

Tags: html, datatable, datatables

I am trying to write a page that will present a provided csv file in a Datatables object.
It does not throw any errors, but it only displays the 'gender' column as a search pane at the moment. I would like all the options to be searchable.

This is my csv file:

name,age,gender,city,country
John Doe,30,Male,New York,USA
Jane Smith,25,Female,San Francisco,USA
Bob Johnson,45,Male,Toronto,Canada
Alice Lee,35,Female,Sydney,Australia

This my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rules</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.1.1/css/searchPanes.dataTables.min.css>

<script type="text/javascript" src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=https://cdn.datatables.net/searchpanes/2.1.1/js/dataTables.searchPanes.min.js></script>
<script src=https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.0/papaparse.min.js></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "results.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                var parsedData = Papa.parse(data, { header: true }).data;
                console.log($.fn.dataTable.SearchPanes);
                var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                    data: parsedData,
                    columns: [
                        { data: "name", searchable: true },
                        { data: "age", searchable: true },
                        { data: "gender", searchable: true },
                        { data: "city", searchable: true },
                        { data: "country", searchable: true }
                    ],
                    select: true,
                    dom: 'Pfrtip',
                    searchPanes: {
                        viewTotal: true,
                        layout: 'columns-3',
                        columns: [0,1,2,3,4]
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        'searchPanes'
                    ],
                    stateSave: true
                });
                var searchPanes = table.searchPanes();
                console.log(searchPanes);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `searchPanes` option, add the following:

```
threshold: 1
```

You can choose a different value than `1` - see [Uniqueness Threshold](https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/initialisation/threshold.html) for an example.

In summary, this value:

> allows the user to define the level of uniqueness for a pane to be displayed.

The threshold is a ratio (in the range `0` to `1`).

Your specific problem is that the default value is `0.6`. That is why some of your panes do not get displayed - their values are *all* unique in your case (except for the `Country` column - but the uniqueness of that column is still above the threshold value).

---

Reference: [searchPanes.threshold](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searchPanes.threshold)